# Jssor Slider in Chrome with SVG background

Tags: jssor

I have a problem with jssor.slider in combination with SVG background. In Chrome (Chromium) it is very slow. If a change the background picture to PNG it is working very well.  Firefox does't have this issue...

Answer (score 0):

If so, you can try `feIimage` filter to rasterize the svg.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/feImage